# How can I display a static block conditionally by way of product page template in Magento?

Tags: php, xml, magento

Here is the situation.  We have a configurator extension that we would like to feature on the product page of only specific products. The extension is set up as a static block. My thought was that I could use an if statement in PHP using XML to define the template.

Here is my catalog XML:

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="partfinder/selector" name="partfinder_selector" template="partfinder/selector.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

This is my PHP in the view.php file:

```
<?php
if ($_product->getSku() = 10007)
{
echo $this->getChildHtml('partfinder_selector');
}
?>
```

What am I missing? Right now, this just destroys my product pages; all of them.

Is there a better way to do what I am trying to accomplish?  I know it is bad form to use CMS blocks this way, however, that seems to be the nature of the extension.

Comment: I think you forgot an `=` sign. `if ($_product->getSku() = 10007)` should be `if ($_product->getSku() == 10007)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use as follows :

```
<?php 
if ($_product->getSku() == '10007') {
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('partfinder_selector')->toHtml();
}
?>
```

you also missed == in your if statement.

Comment: It doesn't appear as if the PHP statement is working as intended. The configurator is showing up on all of my product pages.  Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried printing the sku code and try echo in the if statement.. what output ?

Comment: It is printed earlier in the code as such:
`                <?php
     $_product = $this->getProduct();
     echo $_product->getSku();
     ?>`

Comment: what does echo $_product->getSku(); outputs ?

Comment: The 5 digit SKU of the product.